# How can I pass props to inner React component using functional approach

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props, react-functional-component

I am using react with the following functional approach

```
const Divider: React.FunctionComponent = ({children}) => (
   <div>
      // I want to use color props here of Card
      divider
      {children}
   </div>
);

const Card: React.FunctionComponent = ({children, color}) => {
 const color = props.color

 return(
   <div>
      card
      {children}
   </div>
 )}

Card.Divider = Divider;
```

and I call these components as following

```
<Card color="red">
 <Card.Divider>
  Any text
 <Card.Divider/>
<Card />
```

**The problem is: How can I get the color props in the Divider component**

PS: I **don't** want to repeat props passing again for divider like following

```
<Card color="red">
 <Card.Divider color="red">
  Any text
 <Card.Divider/>
<Card />
```

What I want is the following approach and can still able to use color props in Divider component, how can I do that

```
<Card color="red">
 <Card.Divider>
  Any text
 <Card.Divider/>
<Card />
```

Comment: Why don't you want to "repeat props passing"?

Comment: `Card` doesn't accept a children prop anyway. I think that needs to be addressed before cleaning up the API for the color prop.

Comment: I think you shoudl be using props.children should you not in tyour Card. https://frontarm.com/james-k-nelson/passing-data-props-children/ for some examples.

Comment: you can use a context for this component

Comment: Obviously, components are using children props, which I haven't included before as that is not a topic of concern. I have updated the question